# How are a Tesla's batteries charged below 0degC

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

According to [this](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_at_high_and_low_temperatures) link, charging a lithium ion battery below freezing temperature can damage it. How does Tesla manage this problem? I assume they have a solution since they sell their cars in countries that experience severe winters.

Comment: They heat it up.

Comment: That link is ten years old and refers only to general characteristics of batteries.  Specific models can have different specifications depending on their specific type of lithium chemistry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Model 3 battery is cold, a snowflake icon will appear on the console, and the Tesla will disable regenerative charging on downhills and when braking (etc.).

If you navigate a Model 3 to a Tesla Supercharger, it uses the distance from the Supercharger to know to warm up the battery en route, before it gets there.  This preheating may take up to 45 minutes or more.  See Tesla's official Winter "Charging Tips" here: https://www.tesla.com/support/winter-driving-tips

When plugged in (at home at night, etc.), it seems to draw power from the outlet to keep the car warm before scheduled charging or scheduled departures.

Answer (score 1):

The battery pack includes a whole thermal management system to keep them within optimal temp range.

More here: https://www.easyelectriccars.com/why-do-tesla-batteries-not-overheat-teslas-battery-cooling-system/

And here, with some detail. https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/threads/tesla-thermal-management-system-explanation.88055/ tl; dr: there is a 6kW heater to bring the batteries up to temperature when needed.

Comment: The link is interesting but doesn't go into any detail about whether this battery cooling system is used to keep the batteries warm enough for charging.